# Why is $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)...(x-z)=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This problem is taken from **SASMO Grade 8 (Secondary 2)** Sample Questions.

Simplify
$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)...(x-z)$

**Answer:** 0

I think the problem itself is a bit vague. Maybe they write a $0$ because it cannot be simplified further?

I just want to confirm if this is correct, and if so, is there a way to prove it?

Comment: If each letter of the English alphabet is included in that product, then there should also be $x$..... So...?

Comment: Apologize for the tag, I tagged "simplification" but it was automatically changed to "algebra-precalculus"

Comment: @Ak. Oh yes!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In listing out all the alphabets from $a$ to $z$, doesn't $x$ appear as well?

What is the value of $x-x$?

What is the value of $(x-x)*(x-a)(x-b)*(x-c)...$?

Comment: Oh! I just realized! That is mind-blowing! Thank you so much!

Comment: I wouldn't say "it's mind blowing". This question is to be ranked on the shelf "mathematical humour", but it is surely very specious for any level of MO.